# I am having trouble with this integral from the 2012 MIT Integration Bee: $\int\frac{dx}{(1+\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x-x^2}}$

Tags: integration, contest-math, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac{dx}{(1+\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x-x^2}} $$

Could someone explain to me how to integrate this integral.

Thank you and cheers.

Comment: Another question about the same integral: [Stuck in integration: $\int {\frac{dx}{( 1+\sqrt {x})\sqrt{(x-{x}^2)}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1892802)

Answer (score 11):

$\displaystyle{\int\frac{dx}{(1+\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x-x^2}}}$

Let's put $x=\sin^{2}t$, then 
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{dx}{(1+\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x-x^2}}&=\int{\frac{2\sin t\cos t dt}{(1+\sin t)\sqrt{\sin^2 t-\sin^4 t}}} \\
&=\int{\frac{2\sin t\cos t dt}{(1+\sin t)\sqrt{\sin^2 t(1-\sin^2 t)}}}\\
&=\int{\frac{2\sin t\cos t dt}{(1+\sin t)\sin t\cos t}}\\
&=\int{\frac{2dt}{1+\sin t}}\\
&=\int{\frac{2(1-\sin t)dt}{\cos^2 t}}=2\int{\sec^2 tdt}-2\int{\sec t\tan tdt}\\
&=2\tan t - 2\sec t + C\\
&=\frac{2(\sin t - 1)}{\cos t} + C\\
&=\frac{2(\sqrt{x}-1)}{\sqrt{1-x}}+C
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much. Have a great day