# Stuck in integration: $\int {\frac{dx}{( 1+\sqrt {x})\sqrt{(x-{x}^2)}}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

> $\displaystyle\int {\frac{dx}{( 1+\sqrt {x})\sqrt{(x-{x}^2)}}}$
>   $=\displaystyle\int\frac{(1-\sqrt x)}{(1+x)\sqrt{x-x^2}}\,dx$
>
> $=\displaystyle\int\frac{(1-\sqrt x+x-x)}{(1+x)\sqrt{x-x^2}}\,dx$
>   $=\displaystyle\int\frac{\,dx}{\sqrt{x-x^2}}-\displaystyle\int\frac{\sqrt x(1+\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x(1+x)\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx$

I have tried the above integration a lot . But not able to solve further .

Please give me some hint how to proceed or some other method

Comment: Please use Mathjax / LaTeX syntax instead of using a picture.

Comment: @MrYouMath sorry but what is the problem in using like this

Comment: @koolman If somehow the link to the picture gets deleted, your question is GONE!

Comment: Additionally to what @Qwerty said it is also bad for the performance of MSE, because pictures are slower to process and also need much more storage than LaTeX code and it looks worse :D.

Comment: @MrYouMath but sorry it is much easier to me

Comment: @koolman Well, it is _certainly_ much more difficult for me! :(

Comment: @FrenzyLi why are you not able to understand

Comment: Another question about the same integral: [I am having trouble with this integral from the 2012 MIT Integration Bee: $\int\frac{dx}{(1+\sqrt{x})\sqrt{x-x^2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1000886)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By subtsitution twice we get $t=\sqrt { x } \Rightarrow dt=\frac { dx }{ 2\sqrt { x }  } $ $$\int { \frac { dx }{ \left( 1+\sqrt { x }  \right) \sqrt { x-{ x }^{ 2 } }  }  } =2\int { \frac { d\sqrt { x }  }{ \left( 1+\sqrt { x }  \right) \sqrt { 1-x }  } = } 2\int { \frac { dt }{ \left( 1+t \right) \sqrt { 1-{ t }^{ 2 } }  }  } \\ \\ $$
$t=\sin { z } \Rightarrow dt=\cos { z } dz$

> $$\int { \frac { \cos { z } dz }{ \left( 1+\sin { z }  \right) \cos { z }  }  } =2\int { \frac { dz }{ 1+\sin { z }  }  } \overset { multiplying\quad both\quad (1-\sin { z) } \quad  }{ = } 2\int { \frac { 1-\sin { z }  }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ z }  }  } dz=2\left( \int { \frac { dz }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ z }  } -\int { \frac { \sin { z } dz }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ z }  }  }  }  \right) =2\left( \tan { z } -\frac { 1 }{ \cos { z }  }  \right) +C=\\ =2\left( \tan { \left( \arcsin { \left( \sqrt { x }  \right)  }  \right) -\frac { 1 }{ \cos { \left( \arcsin { \left( \sqrt { x }  \right)  }  \right)  }  }  }  \right) +C=2\left( \frac { \sqrt { x }  }{ \sqrt { 1-x }  } -\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 1-x }  }  \right) +C=2\frac { \sqrt { x } -1 }{ \sqrt { 1-x }  } +C$$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $$1-x=t^2\implies dx=-2t\ dt$$

$$\int {dx\over \sqrt x(1+\sqrt x)\sqrt{1-x}}=\int {-2t\ dt\over\sqrt{1-t^2}(1+\sqrt{1-t^2})t} \\=-2\int\left({dt\over\sqrt{1-t^2}}-{dt\over 1+\sqrt{1-t^2}}\right)$$

Now can you solve the rest?

Comment: In your last step how to solve second integration

Comment: Substitute $1-t^2=z^2$

Answer (score 1):

Putting x as (sin ø)^2 works as well.